# How to iterate mapcat lazily

Tags: clojure

I want to repeatedly perform a `mapcat` operation over input. E.g.,

```
(->> input
     (mapcat my-fn)
     (mapcat my-fn)
     (mapcat my-fn)
     (...))
```

Is there a way to do this lazily?

I tried

```
(->> input
     (iterate #(mapcat my-fn %)))
```

But that does not keep a flat structure.

Comment: Can you show an example of desired inputs/outputs?

Comment: @AlanThompson I will create sample input after work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a contrived example where we want to reverse a list of lists of numbers and then do some math on them to produce a single list:

```
user> (def my-funs [reverse #(map inc %)])
#'user/my-funs

user> (reduce (fn [answer-so-far next-function]
                (mapcat next-function answer-so-far))
              [[[1 1 1] [2 2 2] [3 3 3]]
               [[2 2 2] [3 3 3] [4 4 4]]]
              my-funs)
(4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 2 5 5 5 4 4 4 3 3 3)
```

The reduce function starts with the initial list of lists and then applies the first function to that list of lists to produce the answer thus far, it then takes the second function and applies it to the answer thus far to produce the next answer. If you think of more functions you can continue this as many times as you want.

I suspect that it will not make the code much more attractive to look at.

Answer (score 1):

[flatten](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/flatten) should work:

```
(->> input
     (iterate #(mapcat my-fn %))
     flatten)
```

Comment: flatten squashes *all the layers* rather than just concatenating the sequences. so it would fail with `[[1 2 3] [[[1 2 3] 7 8]]]]`

Comment: Original question is asking for a flat structure.  If just first level concatenation is desired, use 'apply concat'.  Note: both functions will return lazy sequence.